# Can you declare an object as itself in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In the example below, is there a way to tell typescript that arr2 is exactly the type it's initialized as?

```js
let arr1 = [{pass: "YAY"}];
arr1[0].pass
let arr2 = [{fail: "NOO"}, 'ok'];
arr2[0].fail //compiler error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as const` will do what you need. It'll type the `arr2` as a tuple (containing an object with a `fail` property, and containing an `'ok'` string), and not as an array:

```
let arr2 = [{fail: "NOO"}, 'ok'] as const;
```